# Replace space between two words with an underscore

Tags: excel, vba

On column C I have values from C2 to C236. Some of them have a space between two words.

Is it possible to use VBA to replace the space with a _ instead?

I guess a FOR loop on column C then when a space between two words is found replace with _

```
for i=1 to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
if between 2 words in column C there is a " " replace with "_"
```

So if a cell in Column C has White Dress, it should be changed to White_Dress.

Comment: Why do you want VBA for this? Select your range and press CTRL + H. Enter the relevant details and simply replace. And if you still want vba, then simply record a macro. you will get something which is similar to what is suggested in the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("C2:C236").Replace what:=" ", replacement:="_", lookat:=xlPart
```